# Splide Video - Youtube videos won't load when using static HTML

Tags: javascript, html, splidejs

I am having a problem with splide video extension, when I am trying to use it with youtube it doesn't load the video, just shows a black screen once I click play.
I've copied the exact example from the docs and put random puppy pictures as img but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@3.6.9/dist/css/splide.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-video@0.6.4/dist/css/splide-extension-video.min.css">
    <title>Splide Video</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="splide">
    <div class="splide__track">
        <ul class="splide__list">
            <li class="splide__slide" data-splide-youtube="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdz__ojQOuU">
                <img src="https://cf.ltkcdn.net/dogs/images/orig/235430-2000x1332-australian-shepherd-puppy.jpg">
            </li>
            <li class="splide__slide" data-splide-vimeo="https://vimeo.com/215334213">
                <img src="https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/GettyImages-1133605325-scaled-e1617227898456.jpg">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@3.6.9/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-video@0.6.4/dist/js/splide-extension-video.min.js"></script>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const splide = new Splide('.splide');
    splide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The youtube video won't load, but the Vimeo video works fine.
How can I fix it?

Edit:
When serving this file (Liveserver / Codepen / Webstorm Live view) and not just as static HTML it seem to be working fine. I am not sure what's the reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Weird but I found that passing the argument     `video: { loop: true, }` makes it run.. without that it wouldn't

Below is a working example... (codepen here: https://codepen.io/alxfmi/pen/poddQMB)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  new Splide('.splide', {
    heightRatio: 0.5625,
    cover: true,
    updateOnMove: true,
    pagination: false,
    padding: {
      left: 0,
      right: '22.5%'
    },
    arrows: true,
    width: '100%',
    wheel: true,
    gap: '1rem',
    video: {
      loop: true,
    },
  }).mount(window.splide.Extensions);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@3.6.12/dist/css/splide.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-video@0.6.8/dist/css/splide-extension-video.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="splide">
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
      <li class="splide__slide" data-splide-youtube="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdz__ojQOuU">
        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/cdz__ojQOuU/hqdefault.jpg">
      </li>
      <li class="splide__slide">
        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/3GNQL3alB-Y/hqdefault.jpg">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@3.6.12/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-video@0.6.8/dist/js/splide-extension-video.min.js"></script>
```